# if (condition), then body onLoad javascript function

Tags: javascript, html, onload

I'm trying to load a popup login form ONLY when the person is logged in...
but this doesn't seem to work...no error messages, but also no popup

```
<body ${$logged['member'] ? 'onLoad="Javascript:showPopupLoginForm();"' : ''}>
```

Comment: try without the `JavaScript:`

Comment: What does this code actually do? Is it even valid JS/HTML?

Comment: is this php? it sure looks like it might be but convoluted

Comment: Agree doesn't look like straight js to me, can you add the appropriate tag to the question?

Answer (score 3):

If you're open to alternatives, I would change the order:

```
window.onLoad=checkLogin();
//

function checkLogin() {
// your code here
    if (logged) { showPopupLoginForm();}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're using PHP to echo the line like so:

```
echo "<body ${$logged['member'] ? 'onLoad="Javascript:showPopupLoginForm();"' : ''}>";
```

You need to escape the double-quotes:

```
echo "<body ${$logged['member'] ? 'onLoad=\"Javascript:showPopupLoginForm();\"' : ''}>";
```